# How can I obtain the description of the error when a job fails?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs, ssms, sql-agent-job

I have created a job in SQL Server Agent (SQL Server Management Studio 2012) which executes a series of Transact-SQL scripts. I have also set up one notification to send an e-mail 'when the job fails'.

How can I configure the notifications so that the e-mail contains a description of the error? I would want to know if, for example, it's a deadlock problem or primary key violation problem.

Comment: @Sai That's not a worthwhile edit at all so please stop doing that kind of thing in the future. The post was just as readable before you added backticks to turn things that *definitely are not code* into code blocks.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, I agree that's a wrong click.  So I corrected it.

Comment: is it possible to bring in your sql script to a single Stored procedure, then you can use try/catch and within catch write the error into a temp table.

Comment: Have you done any research? there are many many scripts online that will do this for you.

Comment: I hoped there was a method inside the propriety of the job. 
Nevertheless I'll apply the script into the stored procedures.
Thanks at all.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the very obvious suggestion from Nack.McDermaid in the comments to the question you could do the following:
wrap the individual parts of your procs with

```
BEGIN TRY
--your code
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
INSERT log_table (some_col)
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

or something along those lines. Just lookk up some of the excellent guides on logging here on SO or elsewhere.